# how pass variable as string, then later use it as sympy symbol?

Tags: sympy

I have need to pass to a function, both the integrand and also the integration variable as string. It is not possible to do it in other ways (too long to explain).

The question is, how to do the standard thing, which is  `x = symbols('x')` to define the integration variable (which is passed as string) inside the called function in order to use it in the next call to `integrate`?

Here is a MWE, and showing what I tried

```
from sympy import *
def foo(integrand,var):
    var = symbols(var)
    anti = integrate(integrand,x)
    return anti

foo("x*cos(x)","x")
```

This ofcourse does not work, since `var` is string on both sides of `var = symbols(var)`

Then I tried  to use `eval` to first convert the string `var` which is "x" to variable `x`, but this does not work either,

```
  x = eval(var)
  x = symbols('x')
```

This fail since `x` is not defined.

Ofcourse, I could do this

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')
def foo(integrand,var):
    anti = integrate(integrand,x)
    return anti

foo("x*cos(x)","x")
```

But this is not what I want, since the function `foo` being called, needs to be called with different integration variables from outside, and these have to be strings.

Any suggestion how to handle this? Notice that the issue is with the integration variable only. sympy integrate accepts the integrand as string with no problem, but not the integration variable.  So this would also fail

```
def foo(integrand,var):
    anti = integrate(integrand,var)
```

Python 4.7 with sympy 1.5

Comment: `sympify("x*cos(x)") `

Comment: @hpaulj THank you, I did `sympify(var)` and it worked. The `integrand` can remain as string and it works. Feel free if you want to post this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is almost fine. Just use `var` instead of `x` as the second arg of `integrate`: it is the name of the Python variable that is connected to the SymPy symbol `x`:

```
>>> def foo(integrand,var):
...     var = symbols(var)
...     anti = integrate(integrand,var)
...     return anti
...

>>> foo("x*cos(x)","x")
x*sin(x) + cos(x)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Also suggestion to use `sympify(var)` works as well. I must have overlooked trying it as you show.

Comment: `sympify` is the swiss-army-knife method of changing a string into something SymPy-like; `symbols` is the scalpel; `Symbol`, the laser-beam.